# JOOMLA 2.5 / Login with an AJAX Request

Tags: ajax, joomla, authentication, request

is there an posibility to get an Session ID, maybe from an ajax request to an joomla instance?

thank you for feedback!

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried? Anything is possible with enough effort.

Answer (score 0):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication

At least two of the extensions listed have AJAX in their names.

Comment: like on http://forum.joomla.org/ ;)

we use an single sign on, for authentification , cant use an simple extension :(

Comment: Then if you use anything custom made, feel free to post code you have, and code you have tied, regarding making it work with Ajax.